# Tableau dashboard highlight filter by ID

Tags: highlight, tableau-api

How do I perform this selective highlighting if I have two plots that aggregates using somewhat unrelated information? I understand that sheets of a dashboard can be highlighted together when a user clicks on an item in any of the sheets.

For example, with the data below, I try to have 2 scatter plots of Quantity x Amount - 1 with Origin as the details/label, and another with the Categories. I put them in the same dashboard, and I want the user to be able to click on the Japan circle and see in which Categories we have Japanese products - i.e. highlight all the marks in the other chart where Japan is the Origin. The link to both charts is the Product IDs. This is a simplified example of what I want to do. I have a lot more records and sheets.

```
Product ID  Origin  Categories  Quantity    Amount
1           Japan   Fruit       W           $10
2           China   Fruit       X           $20
3           Japan   Delicacy    Y           $30
4           China   Delicacy    Z           $40
```

To put it another way, I want the highlighting action to also highlight the other sheets in the dashboard/workbook (whichever is feasible) based on the value of the attribute highlighted.

Comment: Not sure if it suits your needs, but action filters is a way: http://kb.tableausoftware.com/articles/knowledgebase/creating-filter-actions-dashboards

Comment: That might not be feasible for me because i will need multiple filters with lots of dimension values... Was looking for a more intuitive way to let users explore the dash

Comment: Action filters are a very intuitive way for users to explore the dash. Anyway, you can always use parameters. Not fancy, not super user-friendly, but always do the trick

Comment: Action filters are not exactly what I wanted, but I suppose it is a good compromise. Thanks for the help!

This link seems to produce a more intuitive result than the link you posted: http://mkt.tableau.com/files/quickstart/feature-guides/actions_filter.pdf